# loop colocalisation in r

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to loop colocalisation analyses in R https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coloc/coloc.pdf. using the R package *coloc*. The function *coloc.abf* is called on a dataset which consists of ~1000 SNPs and the corresponding betas, p values and se.

```
result <- coloc.abf(dataset$p1, dataset$beta1, dataset$se1, dataset$p2, dataset$beta2, dataset$se2)
```

This code runs coloc for the whole dataset. The output is:

```
PP.H0.abf PP.H1.abf PP.H2.abf PP.H3.abf PP.H4.abf 
6.31e-100  9.92e-01 1.63e-102  2.56e-03  5.09e-03 
[1] "PP abf for shared variant: 0.509%"
```

However I want to run it for each of the SNPs individually.

I have tried to *lapply*

```
individual <- lapply(dataset[c(1:1000),], function(i){

result <- coloc.abf(dataset$p1, dataset$beta1, dataset$se1, dataset$p2, dataset$beta2, dataset$se2)

})
```

But this just gives me the above output 1000 times

```
PP.H0.abf PP.H1.abf PP.H2.abf PP.H3.abf PP.H4.abf 
6.31e-100  9.92e-01 1.63e-102  2.56e-03  5.09e-03 
[1] "PP abf for shared variant: 0.509%"
```

How do I amend this loop so it runs the analysis on each SNP/row, and gives ~1000 different results?

Thanks!

Comment: We need to add the index i: `coloc.abf(dataset$p1[ i ], dataset$beta1[ i ], dataset$se1[ i ], dataset$p2[ i ], dataset$beta2[ i ], dataset$se2[ i ])`

Comment: I see! Thank you! Can I accept this as the answer?

Comment: No, let’s close it as typo :)